# Binding click function on each div JQuery

Tags: jquery, each

I need to bind the click function on each div of this ordered list in order to make hide/show an image on each imgXX div, I'm newbie with JQuery

```
<ol id='selectable'>
 <li class="ui-state-default">
   <div id="img01" class="img">
      <div id="star01" class="star">
          <img src="../ima/star.png" height="30px"/>
      </div>
   </div>
 </li>
 <li class="ui-state-default">
   <div id="img02" class="img">
      <div id="star02" class="star">
          <img src="../ima/star.png" height="30px"/>
      </div>
   </div>
 </li>
</ol>
```

JQuery

```
$('div').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
          if($(this).find('img').is(':visible').length){
                    $(this).find('img').fadeOut(700);
          }
          else{
                    $(this).find('img').fadeIn(700);
              }
   });
});
```

Comment: So what is giving you grief? Umm... ($(this).find('img').is(':visible').length is not correct, I think. is() gives you a true false. Applying length to it might be weird.

Comment: @Sidhart You are right, it should be `find('img:visible')`

Comment: Note that you are binding the click event on the nested div elements, so they might fire twice. You may want to use `$('div.img')` or `$('div.star')` to single out one set of div elements. Also, `.each(function(){ $(this).click(...); })` can be shortened to just `.click(...)` as it applies the event to all elements in the collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `is` method returns a boolean. Use:

```
if($(this).find('img').is(':visible'))
```

or:

```
if($(this).find('img:visible').length)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$('div').each(function(){ 
   $(this).click(function(){ 
          if($(this).find('img').is(':visible')){ 
                    $(this).find('img').fadeOut(700); 
          } 
          else{ 
                    $(this).find('img').fadeIn(700); 
              } 
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Unlike the other filtering and
>   traversal methods, .is() does not
>   create a new jQuery object. Instead,
>   it allows us to test the contents of a
>   jQuery object without modification.

- Source : http://api.jquery.com/is/

So, you can not use length on it as it returns a boolean value. Remove 'length' and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you necessarily need the each.

```
$('div').click(function(){

  var img = $(this).find('img');

  if($(img).is(':visible')){
    $(img).fadeOut(700);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the nesting of the divs, but since you are requesting to only fade the `img` I am assuming that the `.star` div is visible and clickable. The function below is a bit more efficient as I am using `children` instead of `find` which is recursive. Other than the selectors this should work for you.

```
$('div.star').click(function() {
    function () {
        $(this).children('img').fadeOut(700);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children('img').fadeIn(700);
    }
});
```